# how to upload excel file using Java Restful web services and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, excel, rest

I want to take Excel file from html input type="file" and pass that Excel file to my rest method java by http post method. I have a angular controller for that. I want to know how the controller should look like and what should be there in my rest method. I am using Apache POI to process the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a angular method like this:

$scope.exelMethod = function (){

var excelObj = {};

excelObj.name = 'test';

excelObj.age = '20';

//you can write '/excel' as a rest web-service

$http.post('/excel,excelObj).success(function(response) {

```
 console.log(response);// This will be a download path

 //after this call the download function
```

});
}

In the middle layer you can write /excel service and map the excelObj from front end to a class view like this

public class ExcelView{

private String name;

private String age;
}

Now you can use this ExcelView class to map your data using POI. You will have to process the data and pass a download location of the file in the server to FE. In FE you will have to write a download function to download the file from the path you just got from the response.

Comment: what will be the rest method look like?

Comment: @POST
 @Path("/post")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response getExcelData(ExcelView excelObj) {

  //this will be the service
 }

Answer (score 0):

@POST

@Path("/post")

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Response getExcelData(ExcelView excelObj)

{ //this will be the service

}

if you need to know hot to write excel using poi check out this link

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-to-an-excel-file-using-poi.html